# How to create an array for animals whеre the code have to guess by asking question like if it has fur or tail in python?

Tags: arrays

The code has to guess by asking questions like if it has fur or a tail.

```
def array():
    a = array("животни,['котка', 'канарче', 'заек', 'рибка', 'бивол', 'куче', 'хамстер', 'папагал', 'маймуна', 'крава', 'прасенце', 'игуана', 'костенурка', 'таралеж', 'кокошка' , 'овца', 'жаба', 'кон' ]")
print("Намисли си едно животно")
print("Отговаряй с 'да' или 'не'.")
print ("Животното има ли козина? ")
отговор = input("отговорете с 'да' или 'не':")
if 'да' :
    print ("4 крака ли има?")
else:
     'не'
     ask=input( "Има ли рога?")

животни = {
    "питай": "4 крака ли има?",
    "не":  "рибка",
    "да": {
        "питай": "Животното има ли козина?",
        "да": "котка",
        "не": "крава"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can create the guessing game.

```
def guess_animal():
    animals = {
        "ask": "Does the animal have 4 legs?",
        "yes": {
            "ask": "Does the animal have fur?",
            "yes": "cat",
            "no": "cow"
        },
        "no": "fish"
    }

    current_question = animals
    while isinstance(current_question, dict):
        answer = input(f"{current_question['ask']} (answer 'yes' or 'no'): ").lower()
        current_question = current_question.get(answer, "Invalid answer. Please answer with 'yes' or 'no'.")

    print(f"The answer is: {current_question}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Think of an animal")
    print("Answer with 'yes' or 'no'.")
    guess_animal()
```

Please note that I don't have your native language proficiency. The above is based on the language English. Feel free to edit the above accordingly to your native language via Google translator.

> Refer the working code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/gXXxt6OVl)